# Place imageviews along a curved path

Tags: android

I am trying to develop a custom gallery like application in which, i would like to place Image views along an elliptical path whose size varies with position.

All ideas are welcomed.

Thanks & Regards,
Sen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have only two ideas:

- create a path, do the math and position the ImageViews inside a RelativeLayout/AbsoluteLayout on the calculated position. So you only use the path to do the math, not to really position the views on that
- Use 2D drawing (on a canvas) there you can draw images along a path... how to draw a bitmap repeatedly on a path can be seen here: http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg14567.html

Comment: Thanks Warren, I could place some text along the curved path. But i would like to know how can i place some TextView along this path. I would like to select these Textview via a selector. Is that possible. Please Help.